# Using dictionaries with XML (iphone/iOs)

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, dictionary

I want to parse data from a xml file. This is working so far, but I don't find the correct way to get data from the dictionary.

My parser looks as follows

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{ 
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Placemark"]) {
        placemarkData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"name"] || [currentElement isEqualToString:@"address"] || [currentElement isEqualToString:@"coordinates"])
        [currentTitle appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{ 
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Placemark"]) {
        [placemarkData setObject:currentTitle forKey:currentElement];
        [Placemarks addObject:[placemarkData copy]];
        NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentElement);
    }
```

As you can see. The data is stored in a dictionary, and this dictionary is store in an array. Only problem is... the key for dictionary is always coordinates. This look kinda logical to me... but I don't find the logic to implement it the right way. Can somebody have a look?

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fill a dictionary, you set objects for keys. To get an object from a dictionay, you need to have the key. And I think that is your problem.

To list the keys in your dictionary, you can use a keyEnumerator:

```
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [myDictionary keyEnumerator];
id key;

while ((key = [enumerator nextObject])) {

    /* code that uses the returned key */
    NSString *theElement = key;
    NSLog(@"Element: %@", theElement);
}
```

With this code, you will list all the keys. To find the object with the key, you use `[myDictionary objectForKey:key];`. If you know the elements in your XML you can access them with this line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are facing is because of the logic you used in

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{ 
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Placemark"]) {
        placemarkData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}
```

method, i.e. allocating the placemarkData that will work fine if element Placemark is encountered first time but for the next iteration there will be problem, follow this idea and see the response on to the console, I am sure that you will find the solution.

come back if any doubt or query in that.